# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many with specific key

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I has two models

```
class Fellow < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :fellows
end
```

One fellow can have some skills, and one skill can be learned by some fellows. So I have third table

```
class CreateFellowsSkills < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :fellows_skills, id:false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :skill, index: true
      t.belongs_to :fellow, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

I want to use method: `fellow.skills`
That invoke such SQL:

```
SELECT "skills".* FROM "skills" INNER JOIN "fellows_skills" ON "skills"."id" = "fellows_skills"."skill_id" WHERE "fellows_skills"."fellow_id" = $1
```

**The problem:** I want to use field `skill_id` in table `skills` instead of `id`, so the query should be such:

```
SELECT "skills".* FROM "skills" INNER JOIN "fellows_skills" ON "skills"."skill_id" = "fellows_skills"."skill_id" WHERE "fellows_skills"."fellow_id" = $1
```

I tried to use different options in method `has_and_belongs_to_many` but the query is still incorrect.

Comment: `skill_id` is this a column you have added to `skills` table ?

Comment: Yes, I have primary key ID in table SKILLS, but while FELLOW.SKILLS, I need to use field SKILL_ID

Comment: You can do this by using foreign_key as `skill_id`. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475088/how-can-i-load-habtm-with-foreign-key-relationships-in-my-fixtures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://cobwwweb.com/why-i-dont-use-has-and-belongs-to-many-in-rails

Instead of habtm, use

```
class Fellow < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fellows_skills
  has_many :skills, through :fellows_skills
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fellows_skills
  has_many :fellows, through: :fellows_skills
end

class FellowsSkill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :fellow
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

Furthermore I would suggest naming the third model `FellowSkill` (dropping the plural on fellow).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I correct my db scheme and call primary key `ID`, so I don't need apply any changes now.